# java.sql.SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: ORA-01400

Tags: oracle, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I've trying to insert data by JPA with spring but it's showing this error
"context":"default","message":"ORA-01400: it's not posible to insert NULL in ("PRACTICE"."TB_ORDER_CUSTOMER"."ID_ORDER")\n"}

my main entity

```
@Data
@Builder 
@NoArgsConstructor 
@AllArgsConstructor 
@Entity 
@Table(name = "TB_ORDER") @SequenceGenerator(name = "order_seq", sequenceName = "SQ_ORDER", allocationSize = 1) public class Order implements Serializable {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(generator = "order_seq", strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
@Column(name = "ID_ORDER")
private Long orderTableId;

@OneToOne(mappedBy = "order", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
private Customer customer;
}
```

And my Customer Entity

```
@Data 
@Builder 
@NoArgsConstructor 
@AllArgsConstructor 
@Entity 
@Table(name = "TB_ORDER_CUSTOMER") public class Customer {
@EmbeddedId
private CustomerPK id;

@OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@MapsId("ID_ORDER")
@JoinColumn(name = "ID_ORDER", insertable = false,updatable = false)
private Order order;

@Column(name = "NM_CUSTOMER")
private String name;

@Column(name = "EMAIL")
private String email;
}
```

My CustomerPK

```
@Data 
@Embeddable 
public class CustomerPK implements Serializable {
@Column(name = "ID_CUSTOMER", nullable = false)
private Long id;

@Column(name = "IR_ORDER", nullable = false)
private Long orderTableId;
}
```

Finally my service

```
public OrderOutbound save(@Valid OrderInbound orderInbound) {   
 var order = orderMapper.toOrder(orderInbound);
    log.info(String.valueOf(order));
    var newOrder = ordersPort.save(order);
    var orderOutbound = orderMapper.toOutbound(newOrder);

    log.info(String.valueOf(orderOutbound));

    return orderOutbound;
}
```

My expect is to save the id from TB_ORDER in my TB_ORDER_CUSTOMER, this orderTabelId in TB_ORDER_CUSTOMER its a FK from TB_ORDER

Comment: Looking at the log, it seems that when creating an order in the service layer, an exception occurs because the customer's ID_ORDER is entered as a null value. Are you creating customer properly in orderMapper?